# Constructing phase diagram given temperature-concentration-phase data

Tags: physical-chemistry

This question may look straightforward to be answered but somehow I can not figure it.

I received these papers [1-2]. Here, the papers (both papers study same system) provide complete information of phases in every point. What I am still mulling on is that usually I was given the phase diagram and locate compositions and phases in the phase regions. Suppose that the phase diagrams are not shown, how can I draw the phase regions from these points? How can I know that at some points outside the data makes transition to other phases when the temperature or composition is varied?

I would be very happy if someone can explain me to draw the phase regions as shown in the papers.

Thank you.

**References**

1. Campbell, A. N., Campbell, A. J. R. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **59,** 2481-2488 (1937).
2. Rhodes, F. H., Markley, A. L. *J. Phys. Chem.* **25,** 527-534 (1921).

**Images**

From ref. 1

[image]

https://pasteboard.co/J54SVM6.png

[image]

https://pasteboard.co/J54T2yI.png

From ref. 2

[image]

https://pasteboard.co/J54S1VH.png

[image]

https://pasteboard.co/J54SqoS.png

[image]

https://pasteboard.co/J54SDhZ.png

[image]

https://pasteboard.co/J54SM7y.png

Text about above figure

[image]

Comment: "Concentrations, Total and Partial Vapor Pressures, Surface Tensions and Viscosities, in the Systems Phenol—Water and Phenol—Water—4% Succinic Acid", Campbell, A. N., Campbell, A. J. R. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 59, 2481-2488 (1937) https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01291a001 // Paper behind ACS firewall...

Comment: "The Freezing–Point Diagram of the System: Phenol–Water," Rhodes, F. H., Markley, A. L. J. Phys. Chem. 25, 527-534 (1921). https://doi.org/10.1021/j150214a003 // again behind ACS firewall

Comment: @MaxW Wait, I'm going to put the pictures of the data there

Comment: @MaxW Done. I uploaded the pictures on other website than Imgur because Imgur is blocked in my country.

Comment: I added pictures to Imgur so that they will stay with the question.

Comment: Figure 1 in last image is the phase diagram for the phenol/water system. Presumably the letters on the diagram would be described in the article's text.

Comment: @MaxW Here is the description of the letters https://pasteboard.co/J5517x1.png

Comment: @MaxW Other pages in the paper describes other figures (viscosity, vapour pressure, so on)

Comment: @MaxW I can share the pdf to somewhere on website. Is it alright to put it there for a moment? (I will delete it later).

Comment: some of the user's here will have access to the paper. I've reached my curiosity limit.

Comment: @MaxW Alright :)